# CSS HTML Content fitting at a height between to areas

Tags: html, css

I am making a responsive site for a mobile. The HTML should not be changed but the css should handle the positioning of the elements so as to not effect the main site.

**BACKGROUND INFORMATION**

The desktop site has a navigation bar set at the bottom of the screen with a contact number below it whilst the site title and logo is placed at the top. For the mobile this is unfeasable so I've put the navigation bar at the top of the screen alongside the title and logo. The number has remained at the bottom as desired. Between the top header and the contact number at the bottom, I have placed the bulk content area. The content is being displayed correctly by using the `height:calc(100% - 336px)` property to set the content wrapper 100% - the total height of the top header and the contact number. The content wrapper is then set absolute to a position top: 176px to meet the bottom of the top header. The content inside the content wrapper does not fit inside the wrapper so `overflow-y:scroll` is used to ensure that the user can scroll through the content area.

**PROBLEM**

The content area within the wrapper is not scrolling.

**CODE**

*CSS*

```
.PageContentBox {
      top: 176px!important;
      height: calc(100% - 336px);
      z-index: 12;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      left: 0px!important;
 }
 #content {
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll; /*This here for testing purposes*/
 }
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="PageContentBox">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="pages">
            <div class="page" id="page0">
                <h1>HEADER</h1>
                <div class="grid grid-pad" style="padding: 0 0 0 0!important">
                     <div class="row" id="r1">
                          <div class="col-5-12">
                               <div class="content">
                                     <img class="megaServiceImage" src="../template/img/gallery/mega/test.jpg" alt="??????" />
                               </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-7-12">
                                <div class="content">
                                     <h2>Applications</h2>
                                     <p class="MegaServicesText">
                                                DUMMY TEXT
                                      </p>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="row" id="r2">
                            <div class="col-5-12">
                                 <div class="content">
                                      <img class="megaServiceImage" src="../template/img/gallery/mega/test.jpg" alt="??????" />
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-7-12">
                                 <div class="content">
                                      <h2>Performance</h2>
                                      <p class="MegaServicesText">
                                                DUMMY TEXT
                                      </p>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="row" id="r3">
                              <div class="col-5-12">
                                   <div class="content">
                                        <img class="megaServiceImage" src="../template/img/gallery/mega/test.jpg" alt="??????" />
                                   </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-7-12">
                                   <div class="content">
                                         <h2>Specifications</h2>
                                          <p class="MegaServicesText">
                                                DUMMY TEXT
                                          </p>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>             
                       </div>
                  </div>
              </div>                  
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `position` on your .PageContentBox: `top:` and `z-index` don't work unless you define `position`.

[Here is you updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fp7pr/) with the position set to absolute.

Comment: that didn't work, I have that on the site at the moment, my thought it's something hidden that's wrong. The site is http://megatron.uk.com
That might help envisage what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you save already given the solution just use that only.
You have specified that absolute but not used it in css. Just use it and it will work no need to put the `#content` css.
css should be like this:

```
.PageContentBox {
      position: absolute;
      top: 176px!important;
      height: calc(100% - 336px);
      z-index: 12;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      left: 0px!important;
}
```

[See the example](http://jsfiddle.net/rajeshwerkushwaha/peLMD/)

I am getting desktop and mobile view like this and I think its fine. What you say?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have put that in my code, and logically I thought this would work too. But if you go to http://www.megatron.uk.com on the mobile and try scroll it doesn't work. I am currently remote debugging it using Chrome and Chrome Mobile.

Comment: I have updated the desktop and mobile view its coming fine I think.

Comment: thanks for looking into it ... Those pages have come out fine ... apologies rajesh, I should have mentioned it was the overview page. Upon further inspection I found that zooming in slightly solved the scrolling issue on my phone but when zoomed out to normal, it wouldn't work as expected. I assume it may be a mobile fault rather then a code fault. If you test those pages that will be interesting to see if has worked on your phone. I should at this point note I have tested on htc sensation and samsung galaxy s5.